# Automator App Launching When Button is Presses in Main Project - Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, action, automator

I am working on an app in Xcode where I am hoping that if I press a button in my main view, it will launch an automator action. Is this possible?

Comment: Would it be ok if you can launch an automator workflow instead of an action?

Comment: Create a new workflow in Automator, place the action in it, save the workflow.

Comment: Ok, so I did that, how would I make it run by pressing a button on the main interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching an automator workflow from a cocoa application can be done this way:

```
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/automator"];
NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/path/to/your/workflow", nil];
[task setArguments:arguments];    
[task launch];
```

Comment: I am really going to sound like a noob, but where do I type that?

Comment: You should have an action attached to the button, put the code there.

Comment: I just did that, nothing seems to happen when the button is pressed.

Comment: Put some NSLog() and check if the action is really getting called.

Comment: NSLog(@"Entering button pressed"); However, this is not the right place to take a cocoa lesson...

Comment: Finally, it works. I just thought that if I hooked up the outlet to the button, it would work, and I was wrong. I just noticed the "received actions" tab and hooked it up, and it worked!